# Hugo - using index with complex key to get data

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

Assuming the following urls.toml file in data folder:

```
[Group]
    link = "http://example.com"
    [Group.A]
        link = "http://example.com"
```

I know that I can access the link value in Group.A in my shortcode like this:

```
{{ index .Site.Data.urls.Group.A "link" }}
```

But, I would like to access the link in a way similar to the following:

```
{{ index .Site.Data.urls "Group.A.link" }}
```

The reason for this is to enable me to pass the "Group.A.link" as a parameter to my "url" shortcode within the content markdown like this:

```
{{< url "Group.A.link" >}}
```

Otherwise, I won't be able to use nesting for logical organisation in the urls.toml data file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having looked at Hugo's code ([Index function](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/3d5dbdcb1a11b059fc2f93ed6fadb9009bf72673/tpl/collections/index.go#L35)) I found a very simple solution.
If we want to pass a complex comma-separated key, all we need to do is split it when calling index. Example:

Using the url shortcode in markdown:

```
{{< url "Group.A.link" >}}
```

Code of the url shortcode:

```
{{ index .Site.Data.urls (split (.Get 0) ".")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested calls of `index COLLECTION "key"` to narrow your way down.
Meaning,

```
(index (index (index .Site.Data.urls "Group") "A") "link")
```

would work given your `urls.toml` structure.

The trick is making it somewhat dynamic, so you don't need to worry too much about depth.

The snippet below might serve as a potential starting point for a shortcode. However, it doesn't have any safe-guards. I'd recommend to add a few checks to get meaningful errors/warnings if things go wrong.

```
{{ $path := .Get 0 }}
{{/* split the string to have indices to follow the path */}}
{{/* if $path is "A.B.C", $pathSlice wil be ["A" "B" "C"] */}}
{{ $pathSlice := split $path "." }}
{{ $currentValue := .Site.Data.urls }}
{{ range $pathSlice }}
    {{/* recommended homework: check that $currentValue is a dict otherwise handle with defaults and/or warnings */}}
    {{ $currentValue = index $currentValue . }}
{{ end }}

<p>et voila: {{ $currentValue }}</p>
```